# run c# code in java

Tags: c#, java

I have a code which is written in c#, how can I run it in java code??

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Run C# *source* code in Java (C# emulated), or run .NET *compiled* code in Java (emulated MSIL)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/) project is a JVM written in .net - designed to allow Java and .net interoperability.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a small chunk of code, I'd recommend rewriting it.

If it is a large chunk of code, I'd recommend:

- wrapping it as a command and running it using `System.exec()`, or
- turning it into a service and making requests using HTTP, a common RPC protocol or plain sockets.

Only if neither of those approaches were technically feasible would I consider something like JNI or IKVM.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at JNBridgePro (www.jnbridge.com), which is specifically designed to tightly integrate .NET and Java code.

Disclosure: I work for JNBridge.